# Swift extension on RawRepresentable has no accessible initializer

Tags: swift, generics, enums, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

I'm trying to create an extension for my FieldIdentifiable protocol only where the enum that implements it has a RawValue of Int. The only problem is that the `return FieldIdItem(rawValue: newValue)` line keeps showing this error:

```
'Self.FieldIdItem' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
```

Is this a Swift bug or am I missing something?

```
enum SignUpField: Int, FieldIdentifiable {
  case Email = 0, Password, Username

  typealias FieldIdItem = SignUpField
}

protocol FieldIdentifiable {
  typealias FieldIdItem

  func next() -> FieldIdItem?
  func previous() -> FieldIdItem?
}

extension FieldIdentifiable where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == Int {

  func next() -> FieldIdItem? {
    let newValue: Int = self.rawValue+1
    return FieldIdItem(rawValue: newValue)
  }

  func previous() -> FieldIdItem? {
    return FieldIdItem(rawValue: self.rawValue-1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In

```
extension FieldIdentifiable where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == Int { ... }
```

the associated type `FieldIdItem` of `Self` is not (necessarily)
`RawRepresentable`, and that's why

```
FieldIdItem(rawValue: newValue)
```

does not compile. You could fix that by adding additional constraints:

```
extension FieldIdentifiable where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == Int,
Self.FieldIdItem : RawRepresentable, Self.FieldIdItem.RawValue == Int { ... }
```

However, if the `next()` and `previous()` methods actually should
return instances of the *same type* then you don't need the
associated type at all, and can use `Self` as return type in the protocol:

```
enum SignUpField: Int, FieldIdentifiable {
    case Email = 0, Password, Username
}

protocol FieldIdentifiable {

    func next() -> Self?
    func previous() -> Self?
}

extension FieldIdentifiable where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == Int {

    func next() -> Self? {
        return Self(rawValue: self.rawValue + 1)
    }

    func previous() -> Self? {
        return Self(rawValue: self.rawValue - 1)
    }
}
```

Note also that the constraint

```
Self.RawValue == Int
```

can be relaxed slightly to

```
Self.RawValue : IntegerType
```